# writing Excel file while using for loop

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to write data to an Excel file, during a `for` loop.
But what I am getting is a single line containing the last data received by the loop.

I have tried a couple of different methods but came short..
2 tries are list below

Any Ideas ?

```
def write_excel(x):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ID_Num.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'ID':[x],
         'mail_one':[Email],
         'second_mail':[second_mail],
         'Num':[Num],
         'date':[Date]})

    row_num = 0
    for key, value in df.items():
        worksheet.write(0, row_num, key)
        worksheet.write_row(1, row_num, value)
        row_num += 1

    workbook.close()

    #df = pd.DataFrame(
    #    {'ID':[x],
    #     'mail_one':[Email],
    #     'second_mail':[second_mail],
    #     'Num':[Num],
    #     'date':[Date]})

    # writer = ExcelWriter('ID_Num.xlsx')
    # df.to_excel(writer,'ID_Num',index=False)

    # writer.save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in List:
        my_dic = {}
        my_dict["ID"] = x
        my_dict["mail_one"] = Email
        my_dict["second_mail"] = second_mail
        my_dict["Num"] = str(Num)
        my_dict["date"] = Date
        print(my_dict)
        write_excel(x)
```

Comment: 2nd_mail isnt a valid variable name. You sure its not erroring on that? Share full error stack

Comment: @User5 Actually it is only for example sake, none the less I fixed it in the code.

Comment: Ideas: [Pandas and xlsxwriter: how to create a new sheet without exporting a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221750/pandas-and-xlsxwriter-how-to-create-a-new-sheet-without-exporting-a-dataframe), docs - [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)

Comment: @wwii As far as I see I am already doing this in my code, but it doesnt seem to work when looping. it is only writing the last data received, not going to the next line, while when submitting the whole data as one, it does, so how do I make it loop ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have xlsxwriter so I cannot test. The documentation says that it cannot modify an existing file so I suspect that every iteration of `for x in List:` you are over-writing your file (`workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ID_Num.xlsx')`).

You can make multiple files with these changes:

```
def write_excel(x,i):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'ID_Num{i}.xlsx')
    ...
# and
for i,x in enumerate(List):
    ...
    write_excel(x,i)
```

Or you could *accumulate* multiple dictionaries and pass all of them to your function

```
data = []
for x in List:
    my_dic = {}
    ...
    data.append(my_dic)
write_excel(data)
```

Changing the function to iterate over those dicts; making a new sheet for each one

```
def write_excel(data):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ID_Num.xlsx')
    for sht in data:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        df = pd.DataFrame(...

        row_num = 0
        for key, value in df.items():
            worksheet.write(...
            worksheet.write_row(...
            row_num += 1

    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Beautifully answered!   I went with the 'accumulate multiple dictionaries' and it worked like a charm.    I placed the name of the dict after the variable `dict_data = account_details` I was actually surprised that it worked (one variable = another), but it did (-: